# systemd background processes

Tags: systemd

In order to handle monitor hotplug I've created a unit that launches a script that detects plugged monitors and do appropriate action, code is [here](https://gist.github.com/Lahorde/8988eb548ba5361512de1ee06952a9cd)

In `monitor_hotplug.sh` I reload different processes using some signals or options :

```
   # Or restart panel 
   xfce4-panel -r

   #reload conky
   killall -s SIGUSR1 conky
```

But in some cases I have to reload process like this:

```
  # restart  plank
  killall -s SIGHUP plank
  plank
```

It has some drawbacks :

- unit active until plank termination
- plank starting must be last command in script
- I cannot start several processes like this

To solve it, I ve change unit type to `forking`, and starting plank as a background process

```
  # restart  plank
  killall -s SIGHUP plank
  plank&
```

Is it the correct way to do this?
How can I restart other processes like this from script?

Comment: IMVHO this is quite a dirty hack. Cannot you just kill `plank` and rely on the mechanism initially starting it to respanw it? Aren't `plank` and the other processes (`xfce4-panel`, `conky`) automatically detecting the change?

Comment: Unfortunately, `plank` `xfce4-panel` `conky` must be manually refreshed when monitor configuration changed. I cannot rely on plank starting mechanism (xfce application startup), there is no option to restart an exited process.

Comment: The problem here by restarting `plank` like this is that it will end up with a different environment, being set in a different systemd session and will probably not be killed properly when closing your session (and will have a wrong security context is you are using SELinux).

Comment: Sure. I've change script to kill plank from `monnitor_hotplug.sh` script. It is automatically restarted using `plank_forever.sh` script that is started from xfce startup application menu. Service can now be a 'simple' service'